# How does one put characters at the beginning of an input line in a compiled program?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently writing a basic console application in Haskell, and I wanted to make it obvious to the user when they're being asked for input by putting `>` at the beginning of the line. Sounds simple enough, right?

Consider this bit of code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr "\nSay something:\n> "
    input <- getLine
    putStrLn ("You said " ++ input)
```

This works perfectly as intended when executed in ghci, however when I compile and run the program, now this happens:

```
Say something:
something
> You said something
```

Can someone please explain to me how and why this difference in behavior arises, and how I should go about achieving the result I have in mind?

Comment: @JohnE. I'm sorry but you're gonna have to elaborate on that.

Comment: Try flushing stdout after your putStr. (I think turning off buffering is, when applied generally, a bad idea.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is due to [buffering](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:BufferMode), you may turn it off by:

```
import System.IO (stdout, hSetBuffering, BufferMode(NoBuffering))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    -- rest of the code
```

or alternatively do [`hFlush stdout`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hFlush) when you need to flush the io stream.